# Floating label inside of border of container in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, label, floating

I'm trying to add a label (title) inside the border of my container. Although there are many implementations of input fields with this feature, I haven't found any for normal containers. Here's a screenshot of what I'm referring to:

[image: enter image here]

I considered adding a background to the text, but since the container's background is different from the background behind it, this won't work as the colors will clash. Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this in React Native?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't implemented this in `react-native` so I can't say if this will work for you, but I have done this in a web app before using a `linear-gradient` background on the label with a little `padding-left` and `padding-right`:

```css
label {
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, #666 50%);
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
```

The hex value would be the background color of your input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but sadly it doesnt really work that easily in react native since there isnt a option to us linear gradient out of the box. I tried it with two views and then putting a flex 1 on it but and it kinda worked but then if the label title changes or the height of the container everything breaks.